# VBA to copy a specific cell and paste into adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create VBA code that copies and pastes data from a specific cell into a series of cells until its empty. I do not have great experience with VBA and so I am struggling to create such a code.

I would like to create a code that loops for an entire set of data so for example B2 cell would need to copied in cell from A5 until A9. Then, B12 would be copied from A15 until A19.

And all the way down until the list was completed[Copied Data].[Data Before Copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4cHX.png)[New Result Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uSej.png) [Data copy into different column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfIX1.png)[image: Column B date missing but still copied data]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the ranges that you need to fill likely to change? Otherwise, you could just hard code `range("A5:A9").value2 = range("B2").value2`

Comment: The bad thing in my comment is that the workbook and worksheet names are not qualified (meaning code will overwrite on whatever sheet is active), good thing is it's easy to qualify

Comment: @chillin thanks for your insight. i did think about this too however the sheet contains over 1000 rows of the data with the same format (i.e) It starts with a unique number then followed by a empty row, then headers, then 5 days and it continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach. Is dynamic and you can increase or decrease the range in Columna A (yellow part)

---

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")     'Sheet name
Dim lrow As Long
Dim cl As Variant
Dim myRange As Range
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim currentRowValue As String
Dim currRow As Long

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row     'Find last row in Sheet1
Set myRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(lrow, 2)) 'Range you want to loop through in Column B, from row 1 to last row

For Each cl In myRange
    Debug.Print cl
    If cl.Value <> "" And cl.Value <> "Day Date" And Not IsDate(cl.Value) Then 'Ignore empty cells, Cells with the word "Day Date" or if the cells contain a date
        For currentRow = cl.Row + 2 To cl.Row + 10
            currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
            If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then 'Checks for empty rows in the area below
                currRow = Cells(currentRow, 2).Row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Range(Cells(cl.Row, 1).Offset(3, 0), Cells(currRow - 1, 1)) = Cells(cl.Row, 2) 'Set current value in Column B to the adjacent range (Column A). Offset(3, 0) - this part sets the first cell in the range. Increase "+7" to make range larger
    End If
Next cl                                          'Next value to loop

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

EDIT:
To copy to another sheet.

```
Sub copyNonBlankData()
Dim erow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Sheet name
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Sheet name

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
erow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

For i = 4 To lastrow
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, 1)).Copy 'Copy Serial number
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 1), ws2.Cells(erow, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Paste serial
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 2), ws.Cells(i, 2)).Copy 'Copy date
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 3), ws2.Cells(erow, 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Paste serial
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 3), ws.Cells(i, 4)).Copy 'Copy values
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 5), ws2.Cells(erow, 6)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Paste values
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 4), ws2.Cells(erow, 4)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204) 'Fill Colour in 3rd column
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 2), ws2.Cells(erow, 2)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Add borders to 2nd column
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 4), ws2.Cells(erow, 4)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Add borders to 4th column
        erow = erow + 1
    End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

*More efficient code*

```
Sub copyNonBlankData()
Dim erow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Copy From - Sheet name
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Paste To - Sheet name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
erow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

For i = 4 To lastrow
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, 1))
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 1), ws2.Cells(erow, 1)).Value = .Value
        End With
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 2), ws.Cells(i, 2))
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 3), ws2.Cells(erow, 3)).Value = .Value
        End With
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 3), ws.Cells(i, 4))
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 5), ws2.Cells(erow, 6)).Value = .Value
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 3), ws2.Cells(erow, 7)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204) 'Fill Colour in 3rd column
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(erow, 1), ws2.Cells(erow, 7)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Add borders to 2nd column
        End With
        erow = erow + 1
    End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and exactly what I was looking for. Your example completes my query. Is it possible to copy the data and paste into another sheet after it done the copying. Like for example: Copy row from 5 till 9 and copy row 15 till 19 and so on to another sheet.?

Comment: Thank you, please mark the answer as accepted if you think it solved your question (the little grey check mark under the voting buttons). Thanks :). // Yes it's possible, how should it be pasted (show in a comment with a picture what result you expect :P)?

Comment: Np, I really appreciate the "accepted". Can't see any code ;). You can take a picture of the code or if you want to add a picture of the final result in the comment section... :P

Comment: Cheers for looking into this. As you can tell, I am quite new so thanks for bearing with me on my comments,. Just added a new pic called New Result Expected on the question - hope you can see it.

Comment: Good, You did a lot by yourself. Looks good. I have added my code in the edit. Feel free to ask if there are any questions :)

Comment: Thank you :) You are just a genius. Just a bit more - If I wanted to get the data copied into different column into sheet 2 (Picture added into the question - Data copy into different column) Will that be challenging?

Comment: Give me 5-10 min ;)

Comment: :D, updated my Edit code, really nice to work with you, good result pictures!!! Big bonus. Should do what you want. +1 bonus is formatting ;). Enjoy! You might need to change the RGB colour. Right click on your cell with "yellow coulour" -> Format cells -> Fill (tab) -> More Colours. There you can see what RGB colour your cell uses :)

Comment: You are saviour for people like me :p thanks for being so open and very friendly !!!

Comment: No problem, it's fun to help people :D. Just write if there are any problems or if you have any further questions :). Take care!

Comment: Ohh, I should mention one thing. If you use `Destination:=` or `.PasteSpecial` doesn't matter in my opinion. I think both achieves the the same result. The only reason I use `.PasteSpecial` is that I'm more comfortable with that function (I know it better). :)

Comment: Wizhi, thanks for sorting it out further. I have applied on the actual file and it takes about 5 minutes to copy and paste into sheet 2 as I have about 1000 rows. Is there any tweak can be done to speed up the process?

Comment: Omg, this is much faster than the previous one literally took seconds. Just wondering what was the difference between the two?

Comment: :D! I don't copy formatting, only pasting values. I also make more efficient reference with "`With .... End With`". All formatting comes in the end. And last I turn of screen/calculations updates while performing the code. // You can see the difference between the codes (I have both in my answers).

Comment: Just trying out the code - I am stumbled upon with a challenge. I have embeded image into question. As you can see, the code still copies data into column A despite column B date is empty as the range is fixed. How can I overcome this Wizhi please? The code is related CopyPaste

Comment: This was actually difficult. You have a lot of empty cells that made this tricky. // This part is a fixed range: `Range(Cells(cl.Row, 1).Offset(3, 0), Cells(cl.Row + 7, 1)) `. So when you find your number, it always copy 5 days. I have made a control of counting empty cells in Column B. Give the updated code a try (updated the CopyPaste code. I have duouble checked it with 1-6 days for one number :). Both codes should work togehter, at least in my tests.

Comment: Wizhi, I have tried that however code did not run. After spending some time, I have created another code to delete rows based on blank cells in column B which solved my issue :) Thanks a lot for all your help

Answer (score 1):

My code is bad and may be kind of slow. I have not tested it.

Written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillDown()

' I assume Sheet1, change it to whatever your sheet's name is
With Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")

application.screenupdating = false
application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual

Dim lastRow as long
lastRow = .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).row

Dim rowIndex as long

For rowIndex = 1 to lastRow

If .cells(rowIndex, "B").value2 = "Day Date" then

.cells(rowIndex, "B").offset(3, -1).resize(5,1).value2 = .cells(rowIndex-2, "B").value2

rowIndex = rowIndex + 5
End if

Next rowIndex

End with

application.screenupdating = true
application.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic

End sub
```

Comment: Depending on the layout of your data, this may or may not work. So save a copy before running just in case.